# Issue with setState() in if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

setState() in if statement:

```
// morePage = true
// pageNum = 1

if(morePage){
  this.setState({pageNum: this.state.pageNum+1})
}

console.log(this.state.pageNum); // return: 1
```

setState() out if statement:

```
// morePage = true
// pageNum = 1

if(morePage){
  // ... 
}
this.setState({pageNum: this.state.pageNum+1})

console.log(this.state.pageNum); // return: 2
```

I'm facing that right now and I would like to know why...

Thanks :)

**EDIT AFTER CORRECT ANSWER:**

So yeah I should spend more time reading React's Doc :P
If someone is interested in knowing how I finally did, here is the answer:

In the docs, they say there is no guarantee that your state will have its new value before re-rendering. So you have to use "componentDidUpdate()".

So what I did is, I put the:

```
this.setState({pageNum: this.state.pageNum+1})
```

inside a random function I've created, after that in the "componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)" function I can access the new and the old props values, and there I can use the previous and the current value of "pageNum" :)

Comment: You should checkout my answer if you don't want to use extra lifecycle methods only for this.

Comment: Yep your answer should work too, but my code is way bigger and I've got other things that needs to be in componentDidUpdate() so this is a cleaner solution :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.
> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.

As mentioned it is not guaranteed that the state value will be updated in your next line of code.

If you want to check the state for debugging try logging it in `render` method, as this method is invoked after the state is updated

Comment: The code is logging `pageNum`, not `this.state.pageNum`, though.

Comment: Yeah my bad, I have "const {pageNum} = this.state;" higher in my code :P
Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

So basically you problem is what others quoted from [setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate). But you can easily `console.log` too doing:

```
this.setState({pageNum: this.state.pageNum+1}, () => {
  console.log(this.state.pageNum);
})
```

See the `setState` definition:

```
void setState(
  function|object nextState,
  [function callback]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

With setState the current and previous states are merged. Hence the value. Also, its a synchronous so may give unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTES:**

> `setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state` but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method `can potentially return the existing value.`
>
> `There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.`
>
> `setState()` will always trigger a re-render unless conditional rendering logic is implemented in shouldComponentUpdate(). If mutable objects are being used and the logic cannot be implemented in shouldComponentUpdate(), calling setState() only when the new state differs from the previous state will avoid unnecessary re-renders.

you can get more information from the official documentation 
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html