# setState in componentDidMount doesn't change state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know there are plenty of questions about componentdidmount and setState insde of it. But I can't understand why my this.state.context is null when I console.log it?

Here is a fragment of my component. I draws some figures using canvas.

```
var App = React.createClass({       
        getInitialState(){
            var board = [];
            for(var i=0; i<30; i++){
              var temp=[];
              for(var j=0; j<50; j++){
                temp.push(0);
              }
              board.push(temp);
            }     
            //glider pattern
            board[0][2]=1;
            board[1][0]=1;
            board[1][1]=1;
            board[2][1]=1;
            board[2][2]=1;    

            return {
                width: 550,
                height: 350,
                step: 0,
                board: board,
                isOn: true,
                isPaused: false,
                context: null
            }
        },

        componentDidMount(){        
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");              
            //drawing text
            ctx.fillStyle = "#777";
            ctx.font = "16px arial";
            ctx.fillText("Yonger", 25, 343);
            ctx.fillText("Older", 120, 343);
            ctx.fillText("Generation:", 25, 18);
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(140, 198, 101)";
            ctx.fillRect (85, 333, 10, 10);                  
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(30, 104, 35)";
            ctx.fillRect (100, 333, 10, 10);                



            this.setState({context:ctx});           
            console.log(this.state.context);
            this.draw();    
        },
```

At this point something strange:

```
            console.log(this.state.context);
```

console.log will print null!!! But ctx is actually not null!!!

Comment: i answered it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39531547/issue-with-setstate-in-if-statement/39531639#39531639

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setState` actions are batched, making them asynchronous. You can supply a function as a second argument which is called when `setState` is completed and your component has re-rendered. For more info, see: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

This should work:

```
this.setState({context:ctx}, () => {
   console.log(this.state.context);
});
```