# React setState in If Statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I'm making a chess game using React and I'm trying to write a function that computes the squares that should be highlighted when a certain chess piece is selected. I have the game as one component and each chess piece as a second component, and the button in the chess component calls a function from the game component when clicked.

I want to highlight the appropriate squares if and only if the selected piece is the correct color, so I had a setState call in an if statement in my handleClick() function. After reading [Issue with setState() in if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39531547/issue-with-setstate-in-if-statement) I moved the conditional so that the handleClick function is only linked to pieces of the correct color.

The issue now is that the state gets changed as desired, but for some reason the components don't rerender to reflect that change. Can someone please let me know how I could fix this? Here's my code for handling clicks:

```
handleClick(num){
    this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
            gameBoard: prevState.gameBoard,
            turn: prevState.turn,
            selected: num
        }
    })
}
```

and here's my code for creating the board:

```
<div>
    {
        this.state.gameBoard.map((object)=>
            <div className = "board-row"> {object.map((object2) => 
                <Piece key={object2.at} turn = {this.state.turn} selected = {object2.selected} piece = {object2.piece} identifier = {object2.at} onClick = {() => this.handleClick(object2.at)} color = {(object2.at+Math.floor(object2.at/8))%2 === 0?"white":"black"} />)} 
            </div>
        )
    }
</div>
```

Comment: prevState.gameBoard, prevState.turn still holds reference to old, inner object, you need to spread it

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share  a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Aleks The old object is not being mutated, though - doesn't that mean that there's no need to clone it?

Comment: @CertainPerformance gameBoard doesn't get mutated, but selected does.

Comment: @KevinTong No, it looks like `selected` is a *number*, and primitives are immutable; there's nothing wrong there. You're creating a new object which contains some references to an older object, but nothing of the old object has been mutated.

Comment: @CertainPerformance oh I see. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I think the problem is that he is pulling selected state `selected = {object2.selected}` from `this.state.gameBoard`, should be `this.state.selected` instead

Answer (score 2):

try:

```js
handleClick(num){
    this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
                ...prevState,
                selected: num
            };
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ths issue here is mostly a question of dependencies. Your rendering is based on the gameboard field of the state, which isn't being modified. The component therefore doesn't rerender since it doesn't know that there are additional dependencies (selected) for it.

The easiest and cleanest approach I would suggest is to simply move your map function inside a useCallback (or useMemo, both should work) with the proper dependencies, then simply use it in your rendering method.

```js
const foobar = useCallback( () => this.state.gameBoard.map((object)=>
            <div className = "board-row"> {object.map((object2) => 
                <Piece key={object2.at} turn = {this.state.turn} selected = {object2.selected} piece = {object2.piece} identifier = {object2.at} onClick = {() => this.handleClick(object2.at)} color = {(object2.at+Math.floor(object2.at/8))%2 === 0?"white":"black"} />)} 
            </div>
        )
, [this.state] ) 

render (
  <div>
    {foobar()} 
  </div>
)
```

Comment: My apologies for the horrid code formatting, I'm answering this from my phone.